# Yahoo finance API list of all currencies

Tags: api, csv, yahoo, currency, yahoo-finance

I'm using Yahoo Finance API like this:

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=l1

That gives me the current rates for GBP -> Euro.

But how would I get it to list all available currencies?

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=X&f=n0 and http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=X&f=c4` is a start, but I can't get further than that.

Documentation: http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no official list of currencies/stocks supported by Yahoo Finance API.

You can either go to the [currency page](http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-investing), copy paste all the trading pairs and use them directly or use this [xml](http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote), parse it and retrieve both names and prices.

Comment: The xml link is broken. Do you know what the correct link is now?

Answer (score 13):

you want to check this out, it is exactly what you are looking for: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json

Comment: This is in JSON, the question asks for csv.

Comment: Is there a way to get ask and bid?

Comment: question doesnt technically ask for csv. its a byproduct of yahoo finance.

no way to get historical bid asks for free. anyway they are very very tight for major currencies and its not really meaningful because if you really wanna talk about liquidity then you have to care about market depth.

Answer (score 2):

You would just do this:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDGBP=X,USDEUR=X
```

Adding AAABBB=X to the end, comma delimited

Comment: Description: The document you requested has moved to a new location.  The new location is "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDGBP=X,USDEUR=X".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bash one-liner that will use the JSON feed from @swyx and return a sorted list of every currency that is paired with USD:

```
curl http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json \
   | grep USD/ | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -c1-3 | sort
```

It works today, but is subject to changes in the formatting (and of course, structure) of the feed over time.

Comment: cheers, i have no idea what that is right now but i'll def come back to this in future if i need